# Cannot select button for Microsoft login page

Tags: appium, appium-android

When I use Appium Inspector I cannot select the 'Continue' button. The selector does not highlight the button if I attempt to mouse over it.
Instead, the entire page gets highlighted.

[image]

I need to get the element reference of the button so that I can automate the click action whenever the user encounters this page.

This is on an Android 11 emulator device with Android Studio on Windows 10
I am using Appium 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the that Microsoft login screen was a part of the WEBVIEW context.
So I used   ((IContextAware)driver).Context.
I also had to install the chrome driver using:

driverOption.AddAdditionalCapability("appium:chromedriverExecutable", chromePath);

I was then able to inspect it using the Chrome inspector tool.